# deleted item in dataset not deleted in database

Tags: c#, dataset

**Hello everone**

I have a function

```
 public void RemoveStock(string tickerName) {

    int key = this.getKeyFromtickerName(tickerName);
    foreach (var item in listingDataTable.Where(
        x => x.stock == key).ToList()) {
           listingDataTable.RemoveListingRow(item);
    }
    listingTa.Update(listingDataTable);
}
```

Definitions:

```
listingDataTable = new stockDataSet.ListingDataTable();
listingTa = new stockDataSetTableAdapters.ListingTableAdapter();
```

Database type:    SQL Server Compact Edition

The function remove rows from the dataset, but not from the database. All additions to the database is stored but I can't delete from the database.

Do I need to do something else to make the database to accept my changes?

Best Regards
Gorgen

Comment: It is a kind of TableAdapter that is written by the dataset tool when I create the dataset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out that I needed to add an DeleteCommand in my database adapter. The  DeleteCommand wasn't automaticly generated and when using `.RemoveListingRow(item)` no error message was issued, it just didn't work.

In  Data Sources choose "Edit DataSet with Designer" Properties of tableAdaper generate command such as

DELETE FROM Listing
WHERE        (stock = @p1)

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
foreach (var item in listingDataTable.Where(
    x => x.stock == key).ToList()) {
       item.Delete();
}
```

I think this will actually mark the row for deletion.

Comment: with this code I get "Update requires a valid DeleteCommand when passed DataRow collection with deleted rows."

Comment: When I added my DeleteCommand it crashed quite hard, complaining of concurrency issues. But at least your answer gave me the clue of what was wrong, and that is the main thing, I think. :-)