# Can't update data from DataSet to database on C# & SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, ado.net

I am coding a desktop application about stock management with C# & SQL Server. Now I have a problem with updating data from a `DataSet` to the database.

When I delete data from application, the data was deleted from `DataSet`, but it was not deleted from the database.

This is the code:

```
int Pos = SearchArticleIndexByRef(DGVStock.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString());
Ds.Tables["Article"].Rows.RemoveAt(Pos);        
SdaArt.Update(Ds , "Article");
DGVStock.DataSource = Ds.Tables["Article"];
```

Comment: What is the output of this? Show people what you have tried if you wish to get better answers. Additionally The question will be neater if you remove that large bold section pleading for help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [deleted item in dataset not deleted in database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7834376/deleted-item-in-dataset-not-deleted-in-database)

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/feh3ed13.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396 suggests you should be using `Delete` rather than `Remove` / `RemoveAt`

Answer (score 0):

You have to call AcceptChanges on the DataTable to commit the changes made. Doing this will remove the rows marked as Deleted. (Along with any other changes made to the DataTable)